# How do I get a PHP file to automatically run itself from c-panel without using cron job in every minute?

Tags: php, cron, cpanel

I have a PHP file in c-panel, I want to run itself in every minute. I tried to implement this by using a cron job but found the minimum time for a cron job as 5 minutes.

Tried to create a cron job(created to initialize the file first) to call the PHP file and added some code to that PHP file. The code is given below

```
sleep(60);
include_once"index.php";
```

But it's not working for every minute. Is there any way? Please help...

Comment: In your crontab use `1 * * * *` (https://crontab.guru/#1_*_*_*_*)

Comment: @executable OP mentioned they're on a shared host using cPanel, so they won't have access to the crontab directly.

Comment: Anisha - if your hosting provider has limited you to executing jobs every 5 minutes, then there won't be any way around that (unless they have a security vulnerability in their cPanel implementation!). You're on shared hosting, so they won't allow you to consume too many resources of the server by firing cron jobs constantly. Either you must write your application in such a way that you can live with that limitation and still have a reasonably good level of functionality, or you must look for another hosting platform which doesn't impose such restrictions.

Comment: Start by reassessing why you need to run this PHP program once a minute. What's it doing every minute? I'd bet real money that the real solution here is a completely different approach.

Comment: @Tangentially Perpendicular The PHP script is a program for sending OTP via SMS. The client receives OTP in email, I want to take OTP from that email and send SMS to the client's customers.  To pick up and send from unread emails, I wrote a program, that is working in my local whenever I execute and now I want to trigger that program every minute from the c-panel. This is my requirement.

Comment: Then as mentioned before, you'll need to host this somewhere which has a less restrictive cron policy. You might need a dedicated server. Or you can investigate if there is some cloud function service where you can just host this specific component and set a trigger. You need to investigate alternative environments.

Comment: @ADyson Thanks for your help, I will try to check with another platform.

Comment: So you're polling a mailbox once a minute. The reason hosting companies limit acces to CRON is that this sort of polling is enormously wasteful of system resources. You should run your script when an email arrives. Mail Transfer Agents like Postfix have that capability built in, but this is more sophisticated than most web hosting plans will offer. You probably need your own server. Take a look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/178396/run-script-on-receipt-of-email for a starting point.